# How to fix ADODB connection simple login code WPF

Tags: wpf, vb.net, adodb

I have been dying in solving the issue in my code my goal is to simply look for the account relative to the user's input. I have been encountering closed states of  my record set and or having no response at all from my program i need some clarifications on my code and I also would like to know the best practices in implementing a ADODB connection as SQL query

```
Dim WithEvents ErrorMessageTimer As New DispatcherTimer




    Private Sub BTNLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles BTNLogin.Click
        If (Trim(FLDUsername.Text) = "") Then
            LBLErrorMessage.Text = "Username is Empty"
            LBLErrorMessage.Visibility = Visibility.Visible
            ErrorMessageTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2.7)
            ErrorMessageTimer.Start()
        Else
            Dim dbCon As New ADODB.Connection
            Dim dbRecSet As New ADODB.Recordset
            dbCon.Open("PROVIDER=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;Data Source=inventory.mdb")
            dbRecSet.Open("SELECT * FROM [User] WHERE Username='" & FLDUsername.Text & Chr(39), dbCon, ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset, ADODB.LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic)
            Try

                If (dbRecSet.Fields("Username").Value = FLDUsername.Text) And (dbRecSet.Fields("Password").Value = FLDPassword.Password) Then
                    Dim mainMenu As New MainMenuWindow
                    Me.Hide()
                    mainMenu.Show()
                Else
                    ErrorMessageTimer.Start()
                    LBLErrorMessage.Text = "! Invalid Credentials"
                End If

            Catch ex As Exception
                ErrorMessageTimer.Start()
                LBLErrorMessage.Text = "! Account not Found"
            End Try
            dbCon.Close()
            dbRecSet.Close()

        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: To enable people to help you, you have to provide more details about the problem(s).

Comment: Use `RecordCount` before checking the user name and password. If there is no record, the first record is undefined.

Comment: i think im having trouble with my sql command System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Syntax error in FROM clause.'
and upon adding the [] symbol around the table name it runs straight to the catch statement

even though the database contains the account

Comment: Dump the ancient ADODB and switch to ADO.net. No Com interop.

Comment: Do not concatenate strings with user input to build Sql commands. You are risking Sql injection.

Comment: NEVER store passwords as plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I will repeat my comments here so you don't miss them.

Dump the ancient ADODB and switch to ADO.net. No Com interop.

Do not concatenate strings with user input to build Sql commands. You are risking Sql injection.

NEVER store passwords as plain text.

Using Parameters avoids the risk of Sql injections because the values will not be considered to be executable code. For OleDb (Access) the names of the parameters do not matter. It is the order that they are added to the ParametersCollection must match the order that they appear in the Sql command. Not only will parameters protect your database, they make it easier to write the Sql. No single quotes, double quotes, ampersands.

The Using...End Using blocks will ensure that your database objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error.

I don't think your `Data Source = inventory.mdb` will be sufficient for the file to be found. A complete path would be better.

I will leave it to you to research how to salt and hash passwords for storage and then retrieve and compare to user input.

```
Private Sub BTNLogin_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles BTNLogin.Click
    If FLDUsername.Text = "" OrElse FLDPassword.Text = "" Then
        'Make this visible at Design time
        LBLErrorMessage.Text = "Please fill in both fields."
        'I have no idea what you are trying to do with your timer.
        Return
    End If
    Dim RetVal As Integer
    Try
        Using dbCon As New OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.jet.oledb.4.0;Data Source=inventory.mdb")
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT Count(*) FROM [User] WHERE [Username] = @UserName And [Password] = @Password;", dbCon)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = FLDUsername.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = FLDPassword.Text
                dbCon.Open()
                RetVal = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        'An error here is probably due to invalid connection of network error
        'Show the error message not "! Account not Found"
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        Return
    End Try
    'Now your connection is closed and your objects disposed.
    'Only after the last End Using do we evaluate the results of our query
    'and take action.
    If RetVal = 1 Then
        Dim mainMenu As New MainMenuWindow
        Me.Hide()
        mainMenu.Show()
    Else
        LBLErrorMessage.Text = "! Invalid Credentials"
    End If
End Sub
```